Reference request for limit-colimit duality preserving the Gelfand duality for commutative unital $C^*$-algebra
I am looking for a reference for the following result:
If a compact topological space $X$ is the inverse limit of topological spaces $\{X_i \}_{i \in I}$, then the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)$ is the direct limit of the $C^*$-algebras $\{ C(X_i) \}_{i \in I}$, under suitable assumptions on $X$ and $X_i$, $i \in I$ (if necessary).
I would appreciate any references, suggestions, or insights.
Thank you in advance!

You are aware that equivalences of categories preserve all limits?

@MartinBrandenburg I don't know. But, I'd definitely take a look for it. Could you please provide any reference where I can take a look for the fact you said? Thanks.

Assuming you have a basic background in C$^*$-algebras, this handout, written by Ivo Dell'Ambrogio, is very helpful. The goal of the handout is to express Gelfand Duality as an equivalence of categories.
With regards to the fundamental idea behind your question, as mentioned in a comment by @Martin Brandenburg, that equivalences of categories preserve limits, the nLab page, Equivalence of categories, and the references therein should be helpful.
